# In MAUI, cannot remove surrounding pixels from a Border

Tags: border, maui

In MAUI, I want to remove the pixels surrounding the Border.
I am not able to do it as the surrounding top/bottom pixels remains no matter what.
This xaml leaves top and botton pixels (a couple it seems) like inbuild padding/margin:

```
    <VerticalStackLayout Spacing="0" >
        <Label  
            BackgroundColor="Blue"
            TextColor="White"
            Text="header text" />
        <Border HeightRequest="60" Margin="0" Padding="0">
            <Label Text="some text 1" />
        </Border>
        <Border HeightRequest="60" Margin="0" Padding="0">
            <Label Text="some text 2" />
        </Border>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
```

It look like this:
[border screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Geiif.png)

I am running on an android emulator.
What an I doing wrong here?

I expected the surrounding pixels at the top/bottom to go away (just like it seems they do to the left/tight).

**======== Followup on comments ============**

*What happens if you move HeightRequest from each Border to its Label?*

- I made the change, but it had no impact on the outcome.

*If you set Border's Background to Gray, does the Gray extend outside of the border stroke?*

- No, the surrounding pixels are not impacted (see screenshot after the code below):

[image: screenshot after changes above]

*If you set StrokeThickness=2 or 4, does it eliminate those pixels?*

- I was surprised to see that it increased the surrounding pixels (see sceenshot below where stroke thickness of 4 is used in the last 2 borders - for clarity I changed the background to lightyellow):

[image: screenshot after thickness change]

*In that image, I see a single white pixel outside to left and right also - same as top and bottom of each border. (Doubled vertically between the two borders, because bottom of one plus top of second.) What exactly looks different to you?*

- You are correct, surrounding pixels also exist on the left and right side.

Interesting that the number of surrounding pixels increased when you increase the stroke thickness. Can anyone explain that (as that might be helpful)?

How do I get rid of those surrounding pixels?

Comment: What happens if you move HeightRequest from each Border to its Label? If you set Border's Background to Gray, does the Gray extend outside of the border stroke? If you set StrokeThickness=2 or 4, does it eliminate those pixels?

Comment: In that image, I see a single white pixel outside to left and right also - same as top and bottom of each border. (Doubled vertically between the two borders, because bottom of one plus top of second.) What exactly looks different to you?

Comment: Please see my answer in the extentions to the original text above.

Comment: Those pictures look like Maui has a bug that adds StrokeThickness pixels around the border! Report as new issue at `github maui issues`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you just need to set `StrokeThickness="0"` to remove surrounding pixels from a Border.

```
<Border Margin="0" Padding="0">
<Label
    Text="Hello, World!"
    SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
    FontSize="32"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" />
</Border>
```

The result image:

[image]

```
<Border Margin="0" Padding="0" StrokeThickness="0">
<Label
    Text="Hello, World!"
    SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
    FontSize="32"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" />
</Border>
```

The result image:

[image]